# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: django

```
ranges = list(ranges)
            report.date_from = form.instance.date_from
            report.date_to = form.instance.date_to
            report.assigned_range.add(ranges)
```

I am getting the error

```
AttributeError at /create_stock_turnover_report
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'
```

But I can't understand why my database model is this

```
assigned_range = models.ManyToManyField(to=assigned_range, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: what is the ```report```. I guess it's an ```QuerySet``` instance instead of ```Model```

Comment: Please provide your `Report` model.